# Why won't CloudFormation create my database?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-vpc, aws-cloudformation

I keep getting this error on CloudFormation:

```
Cannot create a db.t2.small database instance because no subnets exist
in availability zones with sufficient capacity for VPC and storage 
type : standard for db.t2.small.
Please first create at least one new subnet; choose from these
availability zones: us-west-2b, us-west-2a, us-west-2c.
```

I've got no particular goal for VPC and its subnet other than to securely create and provision my app via CloudFormation. The database must be able to talk to the EC2 instance. Ideally I'll also be able to securely access the database using PgAdmin, but that's not a deal-breaker.

Here are the relevant lines from the sections of my configuration file:

```
DatabaseInstance:
 Type: AWS::RDS::DBInstance
 Properties:
   AllocatedStorage: 1
   DBInstanceClass: db.t2.small
   PubliclyAccessible: no

VirtualPrivateNetwork:
 Type: "AWS::EC2::VPC"
   Properties: 
     CidrBlock: 10.0.0.0/16

PrivateSubnet:
 Type: "AWS::EC2::Subnet"
   Properties: 
     AvailabilityZone: us-west-2b
     CidrBlock: 10.0.1.0/24
     VpcId:
       Ref: VirtualPrivateNetwork

PublicSubnet:
  Type: "AWS::EC2::Subnet"
  Properties: 
    AvailabilityZone: us-west-2b
    CidrBlock: 10.0.0.1/24
    VpcId:
      Ref: VirtualPrivateNetwork
```

Any thoughts on why it's giving me this frustrating error message?

Comment: I guess this might be happening because first you are launching the RDS and then creating the VPC?

Comment: Interesting suggestion but I just swapped the order to VPC Subnet Subnet Database and it made no difference

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that you are in EC2-VPC which have a default VPC associated with it and  all new DB instances are created in the default VPC unless you specify otherwise.

Go to RDS page and look for

```
Supported Platforms
```

If Supported Platforms indicates VPC, check for the default VPC.

Please look at this page for detailed explanation: [Check RDS VPC](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_VPC.html#USER_VPC.FindDefaultVPC)

To suit your requirement I would suggest to create the database in the same VPC as your EC2 instance but maybe in a different private subnet to isolate it? Or otherwise try to create new subnet in the existing default VPC. In the end it's your call as to how you want to go about it, but to achieve DB instance creation in a VPC could you try the below things:

1) Create a DB subnet group and attach subnets to it.
2) Attach the above DB subnet group to your DB instance.

For example :

```
     "PrivateSubnet2":{
     "Type":"AWS::EC2::Subnet",
     "Properties":{
        "VpcId":{
           "Ref":"VirtualPrivateNetwork"
        },
        "CidrBlock":"10.0.3.0/24"
        "AvailabilityZone":"us-west-2c"
     }
  },

      "myDBSubnetGroup":{
     "Type":"AWS::RDS::DBSubnetGroup",
     "Properties":{
        "DBSubnetGroupDescription":"RDS subnet group",
        "SubnetIds":[
           {
              "Ref":"PrivateSubnet"
           },
           {
              "Ref":"PrivateSubnet2"
           }
        ]
     }
  },

DatabaseInstance:
 Type: AWS::RDS::DBInstance
 Properties:
  AllocatedStorage: 1
  DBInstanceClass: db.t2.small
  PubliclyAccessible: no
  "DBSubnetGroupName":{
    "Ref":"myDBSubnetGroup"
     },
```

Please let me know if you face any issues.

Comment: Thanks. I've voted up your answer as I think you're on the right track but unfortunately I can't test and tick it right now as I've stepped back from CloudFormation for the time being. BTW there were also issues with invalid CIDR blocks and overlapping IP address ranges.